# Using async requires async function, but my function is async

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm adapting a [library that uses callback](https://github.com/samcday/deathbycaptcha.js) to use Promises. It's working when I use `then()`, but it doesn't work when I use `await`.

```
> dbc.solve
[AsyncFunction]
> await dbc.solve(img)
await dbc.solve(img)
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

The code for dbc.solve is:

```
module.exports = DeathByCaptcha = (function() {
  function DeathByCaptcha(username, password, endpoint) {
    ...
  }

  DeathByCaptcha.prototype.solve = async function(img) {
    return new Promise(
      function(resolve, reject) {
        ...
      }
    );
  };
})();
```

I believe this has something with the fact `solve` is member of `prototype`, but I couldn't find any information about it. I found that node didn't [always supported async await for class methods](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11688), so I upgraded from node 7, now I'm using node 9.4.0.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't read that error message right: the problem isn't the function you're calling but the function you're **in**.

You may do

```
(async function(){
    await dbc.solve(img);
    // more code here or the await is useless
})();
```

Note that this trick should soon enough not be needed anymore in node's REPL: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13209

Comment: Thanks! Isn't the `in` ambiguous? It says `await is only valid in async function`, but "function" can be the context or the function which I'm calling.

Comment: @rodorgas It is tricky, most of us have been tricked once, but I don't think it's ambiguous if you're cautious enough. And I don't see any obviously better message.

Answer (score 8):

`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` - just like the error tells you, you may only use `await` inside a function which is marked as `async`. So you cannot use the `await` keyword anywhere else.

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html

examples:

```
function test() {
  await myOtherFunction() // NOT working
}

async function test() {
  await myOtherFunction() //working
}
```

You can also make anonymous callback functions `async`:

```
myMethod().then(async () => {
  await myAsyncCall()
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The await operator can only be used *in* an async function.

Answer (score 2):

You may not need `async` `await` abstraction really. Why don't you just simply promisify `dbc.solve()` function with a promisifier like;

```
function promisify(f){
  return data => new Promise((v,x) => f(data, (err, id, sol) => err ? x(err) : v({i:id, s:solution})));
}
```

You will have a promisified version of your `dbc.solve()` and if it doesn't fire an error you will be returned with an object like `{i:id, s: solution}` at it's `then` stage.